Power function in inline 64-bits Assembly on C++ Builder for floating points base
I am using Embarcadero C++ Builder 12 and I am having a giant problem with my power function in Assembly, its called vpow(base, exp). It works perfectly with integers, but I need it to work with doubles. My target is a common PC processor x86-64. Here is my function:
double vpow(double base, int exp) {
   double result = 0.0;
   __asm {
      finit
      fld base
      fild exp
      fyl2x
      fld st(0)
      frndint
      fsub st(1), st(0)
      fxch st(1)
      f2xm1
      fld1
      fadd
      fscale
      fstp result
   }
   return result;
}

What am I doing wrong? I need it working for floating point bases. Like 2,5^3= 15,625. The exp, for now, will be integer. It's 64 bits assembly and it needs to run inline in the C++ Builder IDE.
I tried
double vpow(double base, int exp) {
   double result = 0.0;
   __asm {
      finit
      fld base
      fild exp
      fyl2x
      fld st(0)
      frndint
      fsub st(1), st(0)
      fxch st(1)
      f2xm1
      fld1
      fadd
      fscale
      fstp result
   }
   return result;
}

I just need it to work for doubles too. It works for integers already!

Since assembly languages are specific to a processor, what processor are you targeting?

x86-64, friend.

Did this particular part of your code appear to be a good place to do micro optimizations or why are you going assembler on the power-of function? If I need to optimize, I try to avoid using trig functions as much as I can.

fld loads a floating-point value. fild should be used to load an integer. But on x86_64 usually SSE operations are used instead of the FPU.

@interjay Can you explain better? I tried more than 15 ways and it gave me wrong numbers, NaN, 1 or INF.

@TedLyngmo I am writing the entire cmath in Assembly to a Master degree project. And also to practice a lot because I will need to know assembly.

@VictorMelo Oh, ok.

@TedLyngmo I wrote all of the trig functions but this one I couldn't fix....

exp is an integer so you should load it with fild. Running this line by line in a debugger would easily show you which line isn't giving correct results.

@interjay I tried it too. But still giving me wrong answer. I think it needs an entire reformulation.

@TedLyngmo: Resetting the whole FPU with finit for every call to vpow is not a micro-optimization.  Also, using this form of inline asm forces the operands to get stored and reloaded on input and output, because it has no way to tell the compiler the result is already in st0 so you have to fstp for the compiler to reload.  So as the OP says, this only makes sense as a learning exercise for x87 and inline asm.

Both code blocks look the same to me.  Is one of them supposed to be the one that works for int?   Or for integer-valued doubles?  Because neither of them use fild.  I don't know what actual compiler Embarcadero uses, but clang is the only one of the big 3 (GCC / Clang / MSVC) that supports asm {} blocks for x86-64.  (MSVC only supports this syntax for 32-bit x86).  Anyway, worth checking how it compiles to actual asm, e.g. use a debugger in disassembly mode to check the operand-sizes on fld to make sure it's qword for double inputs, and dword for fild on int.

@PeterCordes I wasn't commenting on how bad or good the assembly code is written. I made an assumption that throwing in some inline assembly in a C++ program has to do with trying to do some kind of optimization.

Your [mcve] is missing any details on what you get instead.  Also, finit will potentially break things if this inlines into a function that's already keeping anything in x87 registers.  (IDK if compilers would do that; it would require them to figure out that the inline asm doesn't need all 8 x87 register slots (https://web.archive.org/web/20230611103408/http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm)).

@PeterCordes I tried to change it and doesn't works anyway.

@VictorMelo - Tried to change what, and doesn't work how?  Now that you're using fild, what register values do you see with a debugger at various steps?  Where did they stop being what you expected / wanted?   What did your code look like for the version that works with integers?  Was it also using x87 math instructions, or is this version totally different?

@PeterCordes Yes, I changed FLD to FILD and updated it on my question. It didn't work either. I think a loop would need a necessary, but I don't know how.

floating-point pow doesn't need a loop.  A typical implementation or log or exp with only basic operations (multiply, divide, add, subtract) and integer bit-manipulation on FP bit-patterns is possible with a polynomial approximation over a mantissa range of [0.5, 1.0) or [1.0, 2), with separate handling for the exponent.  See Efficient implementation of log2(__m256d) in AVX2 .  Or with x87 there should be just a sequence of a few instructions: How to: pow(real, real) in x86

@PeterCordes I am working with Object-oriented programming C++ and it doesn't works well in AVX2. There's another way?

Did you read more than the title of the Q&A I linked?  You can use the same method of separating mantissa and exponent for scalar, or with SSE2; my answer there even links some SSE stuff.  Also, the second Q&A I linked shows x87 inline __asm{} blocks.

The fix is simple. Read the specification of FYL2X or use a debugger. It is a bit odd to be using x87 instructions today on x64 - they are much slower than AVX2 (although still default code generation on some compilers).
FYL2X computes ST(1)*log2(ST(0)) you have loaded the arguments onto the stack in the wrong order! FINIT also removed since it isn't at all helpful.
If it appeared to work OK for integer arguments it can only be because of inadequate testing.
#include <stdio.h>

double vpow(double base, int exp) {
double result = 0.0;
__asm {
       fild exp   // note order of arguments swapped here
       fld base
   
       fyl2x
       fld st(0)
       frndint
       fsub st(1), st(0)
       fxch st(1)
       f2xm1
       fld1
       fadd
       fscale
       fstp result
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
   printf("%f\n", vpow(2.5, 2));
   for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
   printf("%18.9g\n", vpow(1.1, i));
}

Is a sufficient test case to validate that it works for doubles. Output is
6.250000
             1
           1.1
          1.21
         1.331
        1.4641
       1.61051


Thank you a lot, friend! It worked like a charm!
